# length of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am just going through coderbyete questions and I was doing vowel count. This is my program

```
     function VowelCount(str) { 
        var count=0;
        str=str.toLowerCase();
        var split=str.split("");
      // code goes here
      for(var i=0;i<split.length();i++){
        if(split[i]=="a"||split[i]=="e"||split[i]=="i"||split[i]=="o"||split[i]=="u")
        {
        count++;}
      }
      return split; 

}
```

I get an error
`TypeError: Property 'length' of object [object Array] is not a function`
Why is my code wrong? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Remove the brakets after length ;)

Comment: `length` is not a function/method but just a property. Just use `split.length` instead.

Comment: length() is not a function !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes

```
var split=str.split("");
    ^         ^
```

1. `split` is a method and you are naming a variable that in the same line
2. `length` is a property, it needs to be `.length` and not `.length()`

   ```
   var pieces=str.split("");
   for(var i=0;i<pieces.length;i++){
   ```

Comment: Using variable name is split didn't mess up anything. It worked fine with just changing .length() to .length. 
I guess I shouldn't name it the same anyway though

Comment: Even if it didn't, that's wrong practice and leads to writing bad codes. Should not use language's own terms as variables as long as that can be avoided. Try that in another language and that will be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

just use

```
split.length;
```

instead of

```
split.length();
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Really daft of me *facepalm*